# How I can search by key in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

How I can search by value of key [sub1] in multi-dimensional array and display impressions and earnings from there. Array rows can have unlimited of countries.

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sub1] => Spain
                    [impressions] => 1022
                    [earnings] => 0.13
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sub1] => Germany
                    [impressions] => 801
                    [earnings] => 0.01
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sub1] => Italy
                    [impressions] => 684
                    [earnings] => 0.35
                )
        )       
)
```

Comment: yes, it is unique! Like in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sub1` is unique, then just re-index by that and then it's easy to access using the country:

```
$lookup = array_column($array['rows'], null, 'sub1');
echo $lookup['Italy']['impressions'];
```

Maybe test for a valid country first:

```
if(isset($lookup['Italy'])) {
    echo $lookup['Italy']['impressions'];
}
```

Comment: Work great! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, i will do test too!

Comment: Can I get auto countries name from array and display data for each? Means to don't put country name by myself!

Comment: Yes, but you said "search" for sub1.  Just `foreach` and `echo`.

Comment: `foreach($lookup as $values) { echo $values['sub1'].'<br>'.$values['impressions'].'<br>'.$values['earnings'];` }`

Comment: It show me "Notice: Undefined variable: values‌ " and earnings is not displayed, only country and impressions.

Comment: I have resolved with `$values['earnings'],5,'.',',')` because earnings is float and need 4 parameters.